# jquery toggle animate elements disappearing

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggle

got this code below (selecting the first paragraph on a page then applying a toggle function to it, which animates the height (increases/decreases it by an amount).

problem is, as soon as the page loads the first paragraph disappears, as u'll see if u run it (somehow gets a display:none property, which is presumably why it disappears).

anyone know why this happens?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="jquery.color-2.1.0.js"></script> -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('p:first').toggle(function() {
            $(this).animate({'height':'+=150px'}, 2000, 'linear');
        }, function() {
            $(this).animate({'height':'-=150px'}, 2000, 'linear');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, ipsa, ea, et alias architecto iste ipsum velit esse soluta rem earum magni veritatis voluptatem consequatur omnis recusandae beatae quaerat praesentium!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, ipsa, ea, et alias architecto iste ipsum velit esse soluta rem earum magni veritatis voluptatem consequatur omnis recusandae beatae quaerat praesentium!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, ipsa, ea, et alias architecto iste ipsum velit esse soluta rem earum magni veritatis voluptatem consequatur omnis recusandae beatae quaerat praesentium!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well yeah, you have the first paragraph to toggle after the doc ready command has been activated. looks like it's doing exactly what it was told too.

Answer (score 1):

[That toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was removed in v1.9 of jquery.  It is instead using [this toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which shows and hides elements.

**Edit:** To expand on this a bit more.  jQuery prior to v1.9 had two different types of `toggle`.  The one type is the one which you are attempting to use here.  This would allow you to define two functions to be called alternating on each click of an element.  This was removed entirely in v1.9 of jquery.

The other `toggle` simply lets you toggle the visibility of an element.  If it is visible, hide it, if hidden, show.  Since there is now only one `toggle` (the hide/show one) that is what you are actually calling, even though you are trying to call the old (now removed) one.  You will need to re-create this functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) on  `$('p:first')` which will display or hide the matched elements. As you are calling `.toggle()` on DOM ready i.e., `$(document).ready(function()` first `p` will be hidden.

From Docs:

`The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.`